# How to parse multiple rows (strings) in Sybase?

Tags: sql, string, parsing, sybase

I want to parse multiple rows of strings into separate rows. I have searched for the solutions for a long time, but all the code I found did not work very well in **Sybase** (I assume it is because Sybase does not support returning as a table?)

For example, I have a table like this：

```
id    |    text
------------------------------------
1     |    Stackoverflow.is.awesome  
2     |    Sybase.never.sleeps
```

Ideally the results should be like:

```
id    |    text
----------------------------------- 
1     |   Stackoverflow  
1     |   is  
1     |   awesome  
2     |   Sybase  
2     |   never  
2     |   sleeps
```

I have 10,000+ rows to parse, so I am really looking for the most efficient way to do this. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There may be ways to do this in the database, but they won't be anywhere near as efficient as doing this in code somewhere else.  The DB processing languages weren't built to perform efficient string parsing.

Comment: You may d like to check out the following link. http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/10/26/quick-t-sql-to-parse-a-delimited-string/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this. You can split the string in code (most languages such as C#, Perl, Java, etc.) support such functions. Alternatively, you can write your own split function in Sybase using the [patindex](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks185.htm) function in Sybase to get the index of your de-limiter and then use the [substring](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks215.htm) function to extract the delimited strings as [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211555/dom) said in his comment.

Comment: Thanks, I end up using loop to recursively parse out each cell and dump in one column, not really ideal and efficient though.